# Python - save variables as keys and values to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a quiz where `class` is the user's class (either 1,2 or 3), `name` is the user's name and `score` is the user's score. If the same user completes the quiz again, the `class` and `name` will be the same, but the `score` will be different.

What I want to do is store the data as:

```
scores_class1 = {
  'myname': [5, 4, 5, 10, 9],
  'otherperson': [10],
}
```

If the user is in class 1, his `name` and `score` will be stored in the dictionary called `scores_class1` instead of `scores_class2` or `scores_class3` in the format above. Also, if the user already took the quiz once, it will just add his score to the list instead of creating a duplicate key.

Comment: ...do you have a question? Given that this is the same GCSE coursework that's been showing up for a year now, how about you make an actual effort to do it yourself and talk to your teacher if unsuccessful?

Comment: My question is how to do the above. My computing teacher is an ICT teacher that doesn't know how to code and so we're basically teaching ourselves

Comment: then your question is too broad for SO; this isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: if all you are looking for is just how to add a score to the user's, it's pretty easy: `scores_class1[name].append(score)`. In dictionaries keys are unique, so no worries of duplication

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would you make it so that name's scores is  in `stores_class2` because `class = 2` ; how would you check if `name` already exists in `stores_class2` and how would you create a new key called `name` if it doesn't already exist

Comment: You wouldn't store the classes in different variables entirely. You would use a list.

Comment: Make `scores_class1` a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. That way you can just add scores for a particular `name` with `scores_class1[name].append(score)` and not have to worry about whether it's first entry for that name or not — so you don't really need to check if `name` already exists. If you need to do it for some other reason, just use `if name in scores_class1: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't make a variable name dynamic, however you can construct a string from your class_num=2 (can't use class, reserved word) and use that name as a key in a dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

classes = defaultdict(dict)
class_num = 2
classes['scores_class%s' % class_num]['myname'] = [5, 4, 5, 10, 9]
classes['scores_class%s' % class_num]['otherperson'] = [10]
```

result will be:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'scores_class2': {'myname': [5, 4, 5, 10, 9], 'otherperson': [10]}})
```